# onAttachFragment not being called when showing a dialog from fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment, fragmentmanager

I'm showing a BottomSheetDialogFragment from a Fragment. The idea is to get the callback of BottomSheetDialogFragment inside that Fragment instead of activity so I was hoping to receive the fragment inside

```
override fun onAttachFragment(childFragment: Fragment?) {
        super.onAttachFragment(childFragment)
        callback = childFragment as? Callback
    }
```

This method is not being called. I tried using fragmentManager and childFragmentManager when showing the dialog to see if I can get onAttachFragment called but no luck.

```
AccountBottomSheetDialog dialog = AccountBottomSheetDialog.Companion.newFragment();
                dialog.show(getChildFragmentManager(), AccountBottomSheetDialog.Companion.getTAG());

AccountBottomSheetDialog dialog = AccountBottomSheetDialog.Companion.newFragment();
                dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), AccountBottomSheetDialog.Companion.getTAG());
```

Does anyone know how to get this called?

Thanks.

Comment: how did you solved this?

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason it's not calling `onAttachFragment` is because `DialogFragment` control its life cycle and other method overrides differently than the normal ones, see [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment#Lifecycle).

If you simply want to have a callback to the parent fragment, you can either override the `onAttach` method inside the `DialogFragment` and use the context parameter as the callback (cast it), or have a public method inside your `DialogFragment` that sets the callback, which you would call after creating that fragment.

---

`onAttach` method:

```
override fun onAttach(context: Context?) {
    super.onAttach(context)
    callback = context as? Callback
}
```

public callback setter method:

```
//parent fragment: after initializing it    
childFragment.setCallback(this@ParentFragment)//or pass in other callbacks

//child fragment: 
fun setCallback(callback: Callback) {
  this.callback = callback
}
```

Comment: onAttach method I will only get the activity as the context, won't be the fragment.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it a little bit late but now in 2019 with support library `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0` if using variant with child fragment manager then `onAttachFragment` called as I wait.
Here is correct fragment of code on Kotlin

```
ChildInfoDialog.getInstance(it.data).show(childFragmentManager, ChildInfoDialog.TAG)
```

Answer (score 0):

Cannot answer your question directly but here is the workaround you could take:

1. Pass your parent fragment as `newFragment`'s parameter
2. Set it on your child fragment as target fragment with any request code (`setTargetFragment`)
3. Use it in your code as `getTargetFragment()` and cast it to any interface you like (the interface your parent fragment implements of course).

PS.: for the above to work, fragment manager must be the same for parent and child.